# Why can't I increment global variable

Tags: global-variables, scoping

I created a variable q outside of any function.  From within my function I am attempting to simply increment it with a ++.  Will this increment the global q or is this simply appending the value to a local variable?  As you can see in the code sample below I am attempting to use the value of the global variable (which I intend to be updated during each execution of this script) to set a variable which should trigger this function via .change.  The function is initially trigger (when q = 1) however it is not trigger when a selection is made from the dropdown box with id = "selectedId2" which is leading me to believe that q has retained a value of 1 though I successfully incremented it when the function was ran prior.  Any advise of how I can increment the variable "q" for each iteration of this script would be greatly appreciated.

```
    if (q === 1) {
        selectedDiv = '#selectId1';
        selectedDiv2 = '#selectId2';
    }
    if (q === 2) {
        selectedDiv = '#selectedId2';
        selectedDiv2 = '#selectedId3';
    }
    if (q === 3) {
        selectedDiv = '#selectedId3';
        selectedDiv2 = '#selectedId4';
    }
    if (q === 4) {
        selectedDiv = '#selectedId4';
        selectedDiv2 = '#selectedId5';
    }
    if (q === 5) {
        selectedDiv = '#selectedId5';
        selectedDiv2 = '#selectedId6';
    }

    $(selectedDiv).change(function () {

        if (q == 1) {
            var pullDownDivs = '#2';
        }
        if (q == 2) {
            var pullDownDivs = '#3';
        }
        if (q == 3) {
            var pullDownDivs = '#4';
        }

        if (dropDownSelectJoined != null) {
            var dropDownSelectJoined = dropDownSelectJoined + ", " + $(selectedDiv).val();
        }
        else {
            var dropDownSelectJoined = $(selectedDiv).val();
        }


        var SelArea = $(selectedDiv).val();
        if (SelArea != 0) {
            var url = '@Url.Action("NetworkSubForm")';
            q++;
            $.post(url, { RemovedAreaId: $('#RemovedAreaId').val(), selectedNetworkId: $('#SelectedNetworkId').val(), dropDownSelectJoined: dropDownSelectJoined },
            function (data) {
                var productDropdown = $(selectedDiv2);
                productDropdown.empty();
                productDropdown.append("<option>-- Select Area --</option>");
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    productDropdown.append($('<option></option>').val(data[i].Value).html(data[i].Text));
                }
            });
            $(pullDownDivs).show();
            $(pullDownDivs).html();
        }
        else {
            $(pullDownDivs).hide();
            $(pullDownDivs).html();
        }
    });
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a jQuery variable. jQuery is a dom manipulation library.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum - I am aware that jQuery is dom manipulation library, I was just trying to better specify in the title of this post what my question is generally about.

Comment: Where do you define `q`? Can you show the code that defines it? Have you redefined `q` anywhere within the function?

Comment: @Vivin I did define var q = 1; (I need to start at 1) a few lines higher in my code but I failed to paste it above.  I should have been more careful when creating this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but you can see this kind of behavior due to "shadowing":

```
var q = 0; //global "q"
function handler() {
    var q = 0; //local "q" that shadows the global "q";

    ...
    ...

    q++;
    console.log(q);
}
```

Repeatedly calling `handler` will output `1` each time since you are redefining a local `q` within `handler`. However, the outer `q` remains unchanged. But if you did this:

```
var q = 0; //global "q"
function handler() {
    var q = 0; //local "q" that shadows the global "q";

    ...
    ...

    window.q++;
    console.log(window.q);
}
```

The global `q` will be updated since you are explicitly referencing it by doing `window.q`.

Comment: After re-looking over the code I realized I made a REALLY DUMB error which I am certain is the cause of this issue...I misspelled the div names I have set my variables to.  i.e.: '#selectedId2' should be '#selectId2'.  I'm going to be embarrassed about this one for a while.

Comment: Vivin, thank you for your assistance.  Though your answer was not the resolution of this issue since it was the result of my stupidity, your answer enlightened me and did answer my question well so I marked it.